# Break in HREF to move to next line

Tags: html, css

I have the following line.

```
<li><a href="Very_long_text_in_this_line">'Very long text in this line'</a>  
</li>
```

I want to break it in this format.

Very long text

in this line

I tried br but couldn't get the output.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I think `br` does just fine.

```html
<li><a href="Very_long_text_in_this_line">'Very long text <br/> in this line'</a>
</li>
```

However if you don't want `br` then use a `div`

```html
<li><a href="Very_long_text_in_this_line">'Very long text <div>in this line'</div></a>  
</li>
```

Comment: @PankajMorajkar can you include a snippet of your complete code so that I can help you.With what snippet you have provided this is the best possible solution.

Comment: Clearing the cache helped. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 6):

Other method, use `word-break` css

```css
li {
  max-width: 200px;
}

li a {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825280/break-in-href-to-move-to-next-line">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825280/break-in-href-to-move-to-next-line</a></li>
```

Comment: Just `a { word-break: break-all; }` did the job for me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked your code, if you do this it will linebreak as intended:

```html
<li><a href="Very_long_text_in_this_line">'Very long text<br /> in this line'</a>  
    </li>
```

Comment: oops you beat me to it

Comment: Even i thought it should work, but it doesn't. dont know why

Comment: You'll need to provide a more extensive snippet of code, there's no reason this shouldn't work

Comment: Clearing the cache helped. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Good call @Mindless

Answer (score 0):

Just simply put

```
    <br>
```

tag in your link caption i.e. between  and  tag.
Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you need some help with your HTML code. To add a break, simply add a `<br>` to the code. 
Example:

```
    <li><a href="Very_long_text_in_this_line">'Very long text <br>in this line'</a></li>
```

Have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 0):

I found using word-break had potential negative effects.

```
a { word-break: break-all; }
```

In our case, users of our CMS might alternately use the URL itself as the display text, or fashion more readable text for the display. word-break allowed normal text to break at any letter mid-syllable. (Chrome, version 83, Mac)

By comparison, overflow-wrap appears in my tests to create normal word breaks and add line breaks after "/", which is very readable.

```
a { overflow-wrap: break-word; }
```